# Execute code on iOS App Update

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an iOS App that uses Core Data for storing some temporary data. I have created an updated version of the app that I will soon be releasing on the App Store. How do I execute a piece of code once user has updated the app? Is there a callback method that is invoked after a user updates the app?

I want to replace the schema of the existing data store with the newer one. I do not want to migrate any data. Simply reset the data model & data when user updates the app. There's nothing critical stored in the database and it's okay to delete it. Right now, when I update the app on a device it crashes. But when I uninstall the app and reinstall, it works. So how do I tell iOS, "Chuck whatever datamodel was there earlier and start with a fresh, new one!"

Answer (score 0):

on app start up you can check, if a certain key is inside your NSUserDefaults. if not, delete the database, and set something to this key.